# Preforming the same class method on multiple instances simultaneously

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, selenium-webdriver, multiprocessing

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import json


def json_read(file):
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        return json.loads(f.read())

class item:

    def __init__(self, name, level, location, guild, unit_price, volume, total_cost, last_seen):
        self.name = name
        self.level = level
        self.location = location
        self.guild = guild
        self.unit_price = unit_price
        self.volume = volume
        self.total_cost = total_cost
        self.last_seen = last_seen


class web_page_elements:

    def __init__(self, item=None, max_price=None, depth=None):
        self.items = []
        self.depth = depth
        self.max_price = max_price
        self.url = "https://eu.tamrieltradecentre.com/pc/Trade/"
        self.item = item
        self.current_page = 1
        self.op = op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        self.op.add_argument('headless')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')  # options=op

    def search(self):
        self.driver.get(self.url)
        print("on")
        input_field = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/section/div/div[3]/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/input[2]")
        input_field.send_keys(self.item)
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/section/div/div[3]/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/span/button").click()
        self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[-1])

    def data_parse(self, data):
        raw_data = data.text.split('\n')
        return item(raw_data[0], raw_data[1], raw_data[3], raw_data[4], float(raw_data[5].replace(',', '')), int(raw_data[7]), raw_data[9].split()[0], raw_data[9].split(' ')[1])

    def next_page(self):
        if self.current_page == 1:
            self.driver.get(self.driver.current_url + f"&page={self.current_page+1}")
            self.current_page = self.current_page + 1
        else:
            self.driver.get(self.driver.current_url.replace(f"&page={self.current_page}", f"&page={self.current_page+1}"))
            self.current_page = self.current_page + 1

    def data_pull(self):
        # gathers tabl row as elements(objects)
        rows = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//tr[@class="cursor-pointer"]')
        data = [self.data_parse(item) for item in rows]
        for item in data:
            print(item.__dict__)

    def quit(self):
        self.driver.close()
        self.driver.stop_client()
        self.driver.quit()

    def run(self):
        self.search()
        self.data_pull()
        time.sleep(2)
        self.next_page()
        self.data_pull()


tasks = [Process(target=obj.run()) for obj in objs]
    for task in tasks:
        print(task)
        task.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

this is the entire code as essentially it pulls items of a website will all the relevant data an there is multiple items. currently I create an instance for each item inputted in an external file, and then I then wish to take each object in the objs list and call the run class method on each object so that the run simultaneously instead of one at a time for run time purposes however i am unsure that you are able to do this in python

```
tasks = [Process(target=obj.run()) for obj in objs]
    for task in tasks:
        print(task)
        task.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

this is currently how i was trying to do it however when i run the code they still appear to run after the one before has completed and i was hoping if anyone has a solution for this.

Comment: `Process(target=obj.run())` you are *calling the function here*. You are supposed to pass it as an argument

Comment: how do i pass it as an arguement instead @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: `Process(target=obj.run)`